# AJAX Calculator

Tags: forms, ajax, webforms

I'd like to have three separate but interconnected calculators that generate their output with AJAX (i.e., no page refresh).

Would this process work or is there perhaps a simpler/more trodden pathway to do it:

A webform (with webform ajax) with conditional fields, having the other two calculators (still part of the same actual form) be dependent on a given value set in the first calculator.

Alternatively, three separate webforms, with some sort of multi-form submission process?

I'm trying to figure out a good way to have three forms, with a response returned in via AJAX without page refresh. What is the most efficient way to do this in Drupal? Should I use a webform or just custom code this myself?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Webform Calculator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator) module

> 1. Provides a formula webform component for computed values, where you
>      can enter a mathematical calculation based on the other fields.
>      E.g., create a formula field with value formkey1 * 0.1 * formkey2.
> 2. Replaces tokens in the webform body (using webform_tokens) with
>      jEditable, so that users can enter calculation inputs inline & get
>      the results via AJAX.

There is another module called [Real Estate Mortgage Calculator](https://www.drupal.org/project/mortgage_calculator). but not sure whether it meets your requirement or not. :)

Comment: I was looking into that a little bit. I've been doing things the overall way I suggested above, but that may also help. I'll test and get back to you.